# Lambda expression returning 1,3,9 instead of 3, 19

Tags: c#, .net

This could be something simple and stupid I am over looking.

This is my Lambda expression statement:

```
  Addresses = Service.GetAddresses().Where(x=>o.ID.Contains((x.ID.ToString())))...
```

This is my Json return value from that expression.

```
 "Addresses":[
  {
     "ID":1,
     "Address":"Test,
  },
  {
     "ID":3,
     "Address":"123 test street",
  },
  {
     "ID":9,
     "Address":"123 pat street",
  }
  ],
  "ID":["3","19"]
```

If you see my ID object is 3 and 19, but the expression treats them as 1, 3 and 9. I need to get 3 and 19 instead.

Any idea what is causing this or what can I do to fix it?

o is an IEnumerable that contains Addresses and ID

Update:

```
var AllAddresses = AddressList.Select(o=>new AddressList()
            {
                Address = Service.GetAddresses().Where(x=>o.ID.Contains((x.ID.ToString()))),
                ID = o.ID.Split(','),
            })
```

Update:
This is sort of a SQL example hope this helps:
Select ID, Addresses from TableAddress where ID in ( my comma separated string ID )

Comment: Switch to `Equals` to compare exact values, not `Contains`

Comment: @Zippy that does not work

Comment: @HenkHolterman o is an IEnumerable that contains Addresses and ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `Contains` on the string, and `"19"` does indeed contain `"1"` and `"9"`.

It seems, with a bit of guess-work as to what it is you are trying to do, that you want:

```
Addresses = Service.GetAddresses().Where(x=>o.ID == x.ID.ToString())
```

Which will restrict the results to those which actually match the id in question.

But perhaps you want to filter based on a collection of IDs somewhere? (Not clear in your question).

Comment: I think this would be valid if it was 1 ID, I have an IEnumerable<Addresses> Addresses

Comment: There is only 1 ID in each address. What is `o.ID`? It looks from the name that it's only one ID. Where does `o` come from?

Comment: That is an IEnumerable that contains Addresses and ID.

Comment: `o` is a `IEnumerable`? How does it have an `ID` property?

Comment: I think perhaps you want something like `.Where(x => someSourceOfIDs.Contains(x.ID))` or `.Where(x => someOtherSourceOfAddresses.Any(a => a.ID == x.ID))`?

Comment: ID is a string, but then I split it so o.ID.Split(',') to get this "ID":["3","19"]

Comment: Then the result of that would fit the  `someSourceOfIDs` above.

Comment: That is how I had it originally: .Where(x=>o.ID.Contains((x.ID.ToString())))

Comment: But you said, "ID is a string, but then I split it so o.ID.Split(',')", so that's the source if ids, no?

Comment: right, o.ID.Split(',') will return 3 and 19... and the Model may have IDs 1-50 in addition to the address information.

sort of a SQL statement that I mentioned with question update. Select items in this model that contain these IDs.

Comment: .Where(x=>o.ID.Split(',').Any(a=>a.Contains(x.ID.ToString()))) will result the same as I have originally got. ... 1, 3, 9 instead of 19 and 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104193/discussion-between-novicedeveloper-and-jon-hanna).

Comment: `o.ID.Split(',')` is a `sourceOfIDs` not a `sourceOfAddresses` so you would use `.Where(x => o.ID.Split(',').Contains(x.ID))` according to my comment above.

Comment: I will mark this as an answer.. I will update you with result.

Comment: You quite likely had it correct at some point by yourself and then got led into thinking you hadn't!

Comment: haha, you are right, I did ... thank you so much for your help. I got vote down on this question for that particular reason I think LOL

Answer (score 3):

Well, `"19"` contains both `1` and `9`

Post what `o.ID` looks like in C#

Comment: it contains the following: public class Address { public IEnumerable<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; } .......

Comment: o is an IEnumerable that contains Addresses and ID

Comment: Post the full Address class. You can't normally do Contains(string) on that. Did you override the Equality members?

Comment: Please see update of question. Hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 1):

Because both of the objects are lists (from what i understood o contains an `ID` which you split and `Addresses`), you have to iterate through both.

Something like:

```
Addresses = from p in Service.GetAddresses()
            from q in o.ID.Split(',')
            where q.Equals(p.ID.ToString())
            select p;
```

Comment: This one ignores 19. I get 3 but not 19.

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper do you have an object with id=19 in the json?

Comment: say my o.ID.Split(',') returns only IDs, but I have a model that has the IDs and the addresses. I have to filter the return value based on what I have in my o.ID. 

check the following

In SQL this would have worked:
select ID, Address from Addresses where ID in (the comma separated item)